# BluetoothLeScanner is not called in SM-G970N(Galaxy S10e)

Tags: android, beacon, bluetoothlescanner

I developed an App which contain ble function. And this app operated well on my development phone. But when I use this app on Samsung galaxy S10e, bluetooth is not working. And I found `BluetoothLeScanner` is not called. My development phone is galaxy S8 and its Version is Android 9.0(Pie), API 28. And another low version development phone(like galaxy 5, galaxy note 4) operated well too.

But galaxy S10e is same OS with galaxy S8(Android 9.0 Pie, API 28). I wonder why the app is not operate well on galaxy S10e.

I declared permission like that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

And `BluetoothLeScanenr` is called here.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public boolean BleDeviceScan(boolean enable)
{
    logD(TAG, "BleDeviceScan ( " + enable + " )");
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    logD(TAG, "mBluetoothAdapter : " + mBluetoothAdapter.toString());
    if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        if (enable)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "BleDeviceScan Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < MIN_SDK_INT - ELSE");

            timerFlag = true;
            timer = new Timer();
            bleTimer();

            mLEScanner.startScan(filters,   settings,   mScanCallback);
            mListener.bleScanStart();
        }
        else
        {
            deviceShowCount = 0;
            timerFlag = false;

            bHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();

            mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            mListener.bleScanStop();
        }
        logD(TAG, "BleDeviceScan Fin");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

this function is not called in galaxy S10e.

```
mLEScanner.startScan(filters,   settings,   mScanCallback);
```

Should I declare something to use `BluetoothLeScanner` on galaxy S10e? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, scanning does not start because `mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()` always returns false.  Can you verify that is the case?

If the above is true, do settings on the device say that Bluetooth is turned on?  If so, can detect BLE devices with an off the shelf app like [LightBlue](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.punchthrough.lightblueexplorer&hl=en_US&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dlight+blue+google+play&pcampaignid=APPU_1_JvAVXY2bKIu5tAbI0qjoDA) or [BeaconScope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner&hl=en_US&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dbeaconscope+google+play&pcampaignid=APPU_1_ue4VXa61McfQtQbc3qvIAg)?

Comment: thx for comment :). first that is a part of code. so mBluetoothAdapter.isEnable() can be true if Bluetooth is turned on. I declared.
**final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();**
another space. And I Cann't understand what does 'off the shelf app' mean. I use this app for detect Beacon.

Comment: Try using one of the apps linked above to make sure your beacon works.

Comment: @davidyoung oh, I see. I'll try that and comment about it!